# Lyx Dutch spellchecker not recognising any word

Tags: lyx, windows, spelling

I've installed Lyx 2.3.3 on Windows 10 Pro.

The English spellchecker works (see image). De Dutch spellchecker does not recognise any word (see image). Each word is showing up either underlined in red by the continuos spellchecker or in the dialogue as "unkown word" by the spellchecker (F7) with no suggestions.

The document's languages is set to Dutch by Document > Settings > Language > Language = Dutch. And Tools > Preferences > Language Settings > Spellchecker > Spellchecker engine = Hunspell.

[image: Dutch spellchecker dialogue]

[image: English spellchecker dialogue]

FYI: I'v also installed Lyx under Ubuntu (at my home computer) which is in fact seamlessly performing the Dutch spellcheck. So it might be Windows related?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem with the Swedish dictionary. I solved the problem by replacing the files `sv_SE.aff` and `sv_SE.dic` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\LyX 2.3\Resources\dicts` by dictionary files loaded from the homepage of [OpenOffice](https://extensions.openoffice.org/).

It was a bit tricky as the downloaded file had the extension `.ext` and I had to change it to `.zip` before I could extract the dictionary files. I had to make the extension of the file visible by using the ControlPanel.

Comment: I had a similar problem with Lyx 2.3.3 on Windows 10. All English words were highlighted as errors. Using the OO dictionaries worked for me too.